# using guice injection with actor throws null pointer

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, akka, actor

I'm getting null pointer exception on the field injection of a server which is started as an akka actor.

**Schedular part:**

```
private ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(
        new Props(Retreiver.class));

@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    log.info("Starting schedular.....!");
    Akka.system()
            .scheduler()
            .schedule(Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                    Duration.create(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES), myActor, "tick",
                    Akka.system().dispatcher());

}
```

**Retreiver class part:**

```
public class Retreiver extends UntypedActor {

private Logger.ALogger log = Logger.of(Retreiver .class);

@Inject
private myDataService dataService;

@Override
public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {

    if (0 != dataService.getDataCount()) {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    }
```

}

I'm getting null for dataService. Please advice me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that i don't have any binds for this. I expect guice to inject dataService when Retreiver class is created as an actor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For anyone who needs this:**

```
public class GuiceInjectedActor implements IndirectActorProducer {

final Injector injector;
final Class<? extends Actor> actorClass;

public GuiceInjectedActor(Injector injector, Class<? extends Actor> actorClass) {
    this.injector = injector;
    this.actorClass = actorClass;
}

@Override
public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
    return actorClass;
}

@Override
public Actor produce() {
    return injector.getInstance(actorClass);
}
```

}

**AND**

```
Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(GuiceInjectedActor.class, INJECTOR,Retreiver.class))
```

**Thats it...!!!**

Comment: How can you use this along with provider injection? Normally in my GuiceModule I have function like this:
`@Provides @Named("somename")
ActorRef getSomeActor() {
   return Akka.System()...
}`
The problem is that I don't have access to the Injector from inside GuiceModule.

Comment: @Chanan `The Injector can also be injected into your module, like this:

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("jcrActor")
    ActorSelection jcrActor(final ActorSystem system, final Injector injector)   throws Exception {
        system.actorOf(new    RoundRobinPool(3).props(Props.create(GuiceInjectedActor.class, injector,   JcrActor.class)), "jcrActorRouter");
         return  system.actorSelection(ActorConstants.PATH_JCR_ACTOR_ROUTER);
    }`

Answer (score 7):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because Akka is instantiating your `Retriever` actor and not Guice. You need to get Guice to construct your instance and then pass that to Akka, [`IndirectActorProducer`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.2.0/akka/actor/IndirectActorProducer.html) can help you achieve this, e.g.:

```
class RetrieverDependencyInjector implements IndirectActorProducer {
    final Injector injector;

    public RetrieverDependencyInjector(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
        return Retriever.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Retriever produce() {
        return injector.getInstance(Retriever.class);
    }
}
```

Note that `produce()` **must** create a new `Actor` instance each time it is invoked, it cannot return the same instance.

You can then get Akka to retrieve your actor through the `RetrieverDependencyInjector`, e.g.:

```
ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(
    Props.create(RetrieverDependencyInjector.class, injector)
);
```

**UPDATE**

I thought about you comment further, you might be able to turn `RetrieverDependencyInjector` into a `GenericDependencyInjector` by providing the class of the `Actor` you want as a constructor parameter, that perhaps will allow you to do something like:

```
Props.create(GenericDependencyInjector.class, injector, Retriever.class)
```

I haven't tried this, but it might give you a starting point.

Comment: Jonathan, Thanks for your answer. I have lot of untyped actors. So i need a generic dependency injector to be used to retreive actors. How can i do this?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, thats helpful.

Comment: How can you use this along with provider injection? Normally in my GuiceModule I have function like this:
`@Provides @Named("somename")
ActorRef getSomeActor() {
   return Akka.System()...
}`
The problem is that I don't have access to the Injector from inside GuiceModule.

Comment: Why is `injector` being used all over the place? The only place I have it is in my `Global.java` and it's private, so this is very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There can be other ways, eg, you can put a static injector handle in Boot or Some-Injector-Holder-class, and inject when you create the actor by call the inherited method: preStart ()

```
public class Retreiver extends UntypedActor {

    private Logger.ALogger log = Logger.of(Retreiver .class);

    @Override
    public void preStart () {
        super.preStart ();
        Boot.injector.injectMembers (this);
        //Some-Injector-holder.injectMembers (this);
    }

    @Inject
    private myDataService dataService;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {

        if (0 != dataService.getDataCount()) {
        ....
        ....
        ....
        }
    }
```

and also, you can also inject the injector in actor provider to initialize the actor by the injector in a scope of UntypedActorFactory:

```
public class InjectingActorProvider implements Provider<ActorRef> {
    @Inject
    private Injector injector;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Override
    public final ActorRef get() {
            Props props = new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
                @Override
                public Actor create() {
                    return injector.getInstance(actorClass);
                }
            });

            props = props.withRouter(...);
            props = props.withDispatcher(...);
            actor = system.actorOf(props, actorName);
            return actor;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you inject the injector?

Comment: Injector is provided by Guice, no need to inject it.